# Dynamic table in QGIS print layout

Tags: qgis, print-composer

My print layout contains Html table. Sometimes this table can be quite large and require several pages to print. I am using python code to split my table and put each part on a new page. I can't find a way to do this automatically in QGIS. Is there any method?

Comment: You didn't provide any details. But how about Item Properties > Frames > Rezise mode settings? See https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPjdH.png

Comment: Yes, it's close to what I need. But this option has its own issues. Frame keeps the same size and position on other pages. Option "Extend to next page" losts margins. So I have to construct my layout from code, my old hard way (

Comment: Can you insert your python code in the question, please?